# Multiple word search results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search

I'm wondering if it's possible to index of results in MySQL. For instance I have a search term to use which can be one word or multiple words. For eg. "house" or "high sea house". Now I'm wondering if MySQL can index that "high sea house" fit 3 times in a query in contrast to "house" which fit only once.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
select `fields` from `table` where
  `searchfield` like 'high' or
  `searchfield` like 'sea' or
  `searchfield` like 'house' or
```

and so on - depending on how many of them I use in search process.

Now I need to sort the searching process as follows:

1. I need records that contain all the words from search term to indexed first
2. I need to make an evaluation of how many words fit in my search for every word of my search term.

Any ideas?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: you want full text search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: you can achieve it by fulltext search index..but fulltext index supported by either only myisam engine till 5.5 version and avaibale innodb engine also from mysql 5.6 version....so check its documentation provided by @Dagon if either you are using 5.6 or higher version or myisam engine.....

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning
This might answer your question

Comment: Looks interesting this kind of search. I didn't know anything about it. Thanks for ur precious help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT `fields` FROM `table`, (`searchfield` LIKE '%high%') +
(`searchfield` LIKE '%sea%') + (`searchfield` LIKE '%house%')  AS hits
WHERE `searchfield` LIKE '%high%' OR
`searchfield` LIKE '%sea%' OR
`searchfield` LIKE '%house%'
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT `fields` FROM `table`, (`searchfield` LIKE '%high%') +
(`searchfield` LIKE '%sea%') + (`searchfield` LIKE '%house%')  AS hits
HAVING hits > 0
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

It works as boolean evaluations either return 1 or 0. So if e.g. *high* and *sea* are part of `searchfield` `hits` will be 1 + 1 + 0 = 2. The rows are then ordered in descending order so you'll get the rows with the most hits first.

Now I don't know what you store in `searchfield`, but if it contains words separated by whitespace, you could surround the search words with whitespace as well (e.g. `'% sea %'`) so you won't get a match on *seahorse*. That would give you a problem with first and last words in `searchfield` though if they don't have whitespace both before and after.